# DD Command with Override

Tags: linux, unix

I have a question regarding the dd command,
Last week I used the following form:

```
sudo dd if=system.img of=/dev/sdb2 bs=1M
# system.img has 512MB
```

But my image has undergone some changes and I had to run the same command again and I had the answer:

```
512 + 0 records in
512 + 0 records out
536870912 bytes (537 MB, 512 MiB) copied, 40.8683 s, 13.1 MB/s
```

Has the previous image been overwritten in SD?
Why the 537 MB result?

Comment: Thanks @IgnacioVazquez-Abram, you were able to explain absolutely nothing, congratulations.

Comment: This is user support for `dd`, not a programming question.

Comment: @melpomene, so what's wrong ? I published with the programming tags?

Comment: This question is off-topic on StackOverflow in my opinion. SO is for programming questions.

Comment: @melpomene So really I misunderstood the OS premise, the next time I put my doubt inside a shell script.

Comment: Look up the IEEE definition of [megabytes vs mebibytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_1541-2002). Your image is 512 mebibytes = 537 megabytes.

Comment: @thatotherguy thanks about that, and about the override, did you know about ?

Comment: `dd` overwrites the output file, yes.

Comment: @thatotherguy thanks

Comment: Although I've provided an answer, I've also voted to migrate this over to a more suitable sister site given that it's more about the use of the `dd` tool than programming.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww I've never heard about "Unix & Linux Stack Exchange" thanks for the reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two questions are specifically:

> Has the previous image been overwritten in SD?

Yes, otherwise you would have gotten some sort of error message. Of course, it's *possible* that the SD-card device driver could report success even though it didn't write the data but that would be a pretty useless device driver, hence unlikely :-)

> Why the 537 MB result?

In the IT world, 512 megabytes is usually (despite the people who insist in using sounds-like-baby-talk terms like "kibibytes" for the binary-based terms) `512 * 1024 * 1024`, or `536870912` bytes, as shown in your output. It's usually clear by the number in use. If it's a power of two (like 512), it's a reasonably safe bet the "megabytes" is referring to 2<sup>20</sup> bytes rather than 10<sup>6</sup>.

The underlying reason for this is that ISO defines terms like `kilo` to mean 1000 and don't take too kindly to our (mis-)appropriation of the term to mean 1024, and also so disk manufacturers could claim their disks are bigger than the actually are :-)

The `dd` utility is then reporting this as both the rounded-decimal-based and binary-based terms:

```
537MB   512MiB
```

Comment: Using "mega" to mean 1024 * 1024 is almost exclusively a RAM thing. Disk manufacturers use real megabytes (1000 * 1000), and so does network bandwidth (e.g. 56 kb/s = 56,000 bits/s). Your "In the IT world" statement is a bit broad.

Comment: @melpomene, disk manufacturers also used the binary version originally, right up to the point where the marketing droids ousted the techs. In any case, if you're using a number like 512, it's almost certainly the binary variant, since it's a round number, unlike 537 or 500 :-) But I'll edit the answer to take your comments into account.